new TFLite model causing crash
A few days ago, I created a new TensorFlow Lite (TFLite) model using Vertex AI. However, when my app tries to use this new model for Object Detection, the application crashes. The same code works perfectly with the older TFLite model.
The only notable difference I see in Logcat between the old and new model runs is the following bolded line (quote from Logcat below):
"tflite Replacing 16 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 17 partitions."
This appears when running the new TFLite model, and soon after I call detectObject(), the crash begins with:  "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT),..."
Has anyone else encountered this issue, or can anyone help me identify why the new model causes the crash?
Any guidance on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!
LOGCAT***************
tflite Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
tflite Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
tflite Replacing 16 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 17 partitions.
.....
libc ....Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5792 (pool-18-thread-), pid 5589 (...)
I tried to suppress "Replacing with delegate". Changed TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 on my development PC (my dev environment is Android Dev Studio, work with kotlin), didn't help.
